# Help identifying an obscure rendition of Tolkien's Namarie

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, elves, music, galadriel

I found a recording of Tolkien's elvish poem Namarie (aka Galadriel's Lament in Lórien) set to music that I really like, but I can't identify the original artist. It's not from the LotR films and I've tried Shazam/SoundHound but they turn up blanks. Has anyone heard this before or knows where it comes from?

(Apologies for the poor audio quality.)

Comment: It can also be found [here](http://datab.us/1qkjFutNgGs#Namarie), uploaded in 2011 by one DraumurionLawnmower.

Answer (score 2):

I found that there is a book with a collection of sheet music composed by artist  Donald Swann to many of Tolkien poems, with an audio record coming with it. It's called [The Road Goes Ever On](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Road_Goes_Ever_On). It resembles a Gregorian chant and the original singer is William Elvin.

I've heard some versions of [that song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dz6xJ5hv67Q) and they seem to be similar to the video you post, though yours is a different version.